# Can I subtract from an absolute value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, absolute-value

I am trying to prove that this is false: $-m + n \geq |m + n|$ where m is a positive number and n is any number.

Can I subtract n from both sides? If not, how do I show that is false?

Comment: $|m+n| \ge |n| - |m| = |n| - m$, and so $n \ge |n|$, but this means $n = |n|$, so $n \ge 0$. Now this means $n+m \ge 0$, so $-m+ n\ge m+n$, thus $2m \le 0$, i.e. $m \le 0$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $m$ is a positive number, we know that either $m+n\geq 0$ or $m+n<0$.  Consider these two cases:

- If $m+n\geq 0$, then $|m+n|=m+n$, so your inequality is equivalent to $-m+n\geq m+n$, subtracting $n$ from both sides gives $-m\geq m$, which is not true for a positive number.
- If $m+n<0$, then $|m+n|=-m-n$, so your inequality simplifies to $-m+n\geq -m-n$.  Adding $m$ to both sides gives $n\geq -n$, which is not true since $n$ *must* be a negative number.  (Why must $n$ be negative).

In either case, if you assume the given inequality is true, you reach a contradiction, so the inequality cannot be true.

Comment: What do you mean by "m+n = -m-n"?

Comment: @Goldname The absolute value bars were missing.  Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose $m=n> 0$ and conclude

Comment: It depends on how the statement is quantified.  The inequality is *always* false.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $m>0$, the inequality can be rewritten
$$
n\ge|m+n|+m
$$
which is clearly false if $n<0$.

If $n\ge0$, then $|m+n|=m+n$ and the inequality becomes
$$
n\ge 2m+n
$$
that is, $0\ge2m$, which is false.